# AWS CloudFront - Configure Logging, hiding IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am using CloudFront for serving a tracking pixel and Cloudfront's logging feature.

By default CloudFront logs the IP address, but I would like to mask or deactivate logging the IP address due to GDPR concerns.

Is there a way to configure the CloudFront access logs?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to choose the log field on CloudFront, it has a fixed log format and source IP is one of them. The logs are saved in S3 so you have control over the file, you can write a lambda function to remove column 5 as soon as a log file in saved to S3.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html#BasicDistributionFileFormat

Answer (score 0):

The following describes how to anonymize the IP column data:

https://cloudonaut.io/anonymize-cloudfront-access-logs/

Summary:

An AWS Lambda is script is used to open the file and change the IP address.